# Animation with large number of bitmaps

Tags: android, animation, bitmap, surfaceview

I've seen similar threads here but couldn't find a sufficient solution yet.

I'm working on my first Android app and trying to create an animation using large amount of images/bitmaps. I have a list of bitmaps which I like to play frame-by-frame animation
the number of images may change from few to hundreds (currently loaded from resources)

I'm using SurfaceView and using the following to load and draw my images

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), res);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, null);
```

I tried two methods:

1. Pre-Loading all images and caching to memory. This results with great performance
   but takes time to initialize, uses a lot of memory and works only for small amount of images
2. Decoding the images one-by-one. This results with poor performance and high cpu usage

I'm looking for way to boost the performance for large lists, 
Is there a way to cache the decoded bitmaps or convert them to some video-stream (lossless?) to boost performance?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

About performance, 
First do not load the hole image size, use below method to reduce size when load image:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = number; //reduce image size
Bitmap b =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image path, options);
```

Also load images for current time animation not all animations, then load other animations in thread instead of finished animation.

About time in case 2, load images in a [thread](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) and show loading dialog for the user until all images loaded.